# Logging out from Keycloak results in TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logout') within Front-end application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I would like to log out from the Keycloak within my front-end application so I am using the method something like this, but for some reason, I am unable to logout.

I fount many examples online but they are for the old `Keycloak` version so using `auth` and `redirectURI` etc. Can someone please let me know how to logout from Keycloak OAUTH?

My URL looks something like this:

```
KEYCLOAK_LOGOUT_URL=http://localhost:9080/realms/{myRealmName}/protocol/openid-connect/logout
```

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const initOptions = useState("initOptions", () => ({
  realm: config.public.KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME,
  clientId: config.public.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
  url: config.public.KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
}));

// Create a new instance of the Keycloak constructor
const keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions.value);

//Generate the token
export async function fetchToken(router) {
  try {
    // Initialize Keycloak and handle the authentication
    const auth = await keycloak.init({
      onLoad: "login-required",
      flow: "implicit",
    });

    //If not authenticated then reload to show login page
    if (!auth) {
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      console.log("User is authenticated");
    }

    // Check if the token is expired
    const tokenExpired = keycloak.isTokenExpired();

    if (tokenExpired) {
      console.log("Token is expired. Redirecting to login page...");
      // Redirect to the login page
      await keycloak.login({ redirectUri: window.location.href });
    }

    //If token is present then store it in localstorage
    if (keycloak.token) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("keycloakToken", keycloak.token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("idToken", keycloak.idToken);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error initializing Keycloak:", error);
  }
}

//Method to Logout user from Keycloak based on IDToken
export async function logout() {
  console.log("NEW LOGOUT FROM FETCH");
  const logoutURL =
    config.public.KEYCLOAK_LOGOUT_URL +
    "?id_token_hint=" +
    localStorage.getItem("idToken") +
    "&post_logout_redirect_uri=" +
    "https://google.com";
  console.log(logoutURL);
  console.log(encodeURIComponent(window.location.href));

  const keycloak = new Keycloak({
    url: config.public.KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
    realm: config.public.KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME,
    clientId: config.public.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
  });

  // Initialize Keycloak
  await keycloak.init({ onLoad: "login-required", flow: "implicit" });

  keycloak
    .logout({ redirectUri: logoutURL })
    .then((success) => {
      console.log("--> log: logout success ", success);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("--> log: logout error ", error);
    });
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logout')
    at Keycloak.kc.logout (keycloak-js.js?v=59798791:988:20)
```

However, I am able to login to my Server using the method mentioned in the above code.

The login method is working fine and I am able to log in and obtain the `token` and `idToken` but unable to logout.

Comment: Can you try log keycloak before call `keycloak.logout` method?

Comment: @Aminarune Thanks a lot for the response. Actually, after trying some methods I was able to make it work. I have added the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer as it can be helpful to someone in the future. There are a lot of changes in the recent Keycloak version and most of the answers here are for an old version of Keycloak.

The following approach worked for me to log into `Keycloak` and log out of the `Keycloak` using the `Vue 3 or Nuxt 3` front-end application and using the `Keycloak-js` library.

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const initOptions = useState("initOptions", () => ({
  realm: config.public.KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME,
  clientId: config.public.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
  url: config.public.KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
}));

// Create a new instance of the Keycloak constructor
const keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions.value);

//Function to login to Keycloak and generate token and ID token
export async function keycloakLogin() {
  try {
    // Initialize Keycloak and handle the authentication
    const auth = await keycloak.init({
      onLoad: "login-required",
      flow: "implicit",
    });

    //If not authenticated then reload to show login page
    if (!auth) {
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      console.log("User is authenticated");
    }

    //If token is present then store it in localstorage
    if (keycloak.token) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("keycloakToken", keycloak.token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("idToken", keycloak.idToken);
    }

    // Call the setupTokenChecking function to initiate token checking
    setupTokenChecking();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error initializing Keycloak:", error);
  }
}

export async function keycloakLogout() {
  const logoutURL =
    config.public.KEYCLOAK_LOGOUT_URL +
    "?id_token_hint=" +
    localStorage.getItem("idToken") +
    "&post_logout_redirect_uri=" +
    encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);

  keycloak
    .logout({ redirectUri: logoutURL })
    .then((success) => {
      console.log("User logout success ", success);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("User logout error ", error);
    });
}


// Call the checkAndRenewToken function initially and set up periodic checks
async function setupTokenChecking() {
  await checkAndRenewToken(); // Check the token immediately upon setup
  const tokenCheckInterval = 5 * 60 * 1000; // periodic token checks for 5 minutes in milliseconds
  setInterval(checkAndRenewToken, tokenCheckInterval);
}

// Function to periodically check and renew the Keycloak token
export async function checkAndRenewToken() {
  try {
    if (keycloak.isTokenExpired()) {
      console.log("Token is expired. Renewing token...");
      try {
        await keycloak.updateToken(60);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "Refresh Token Failed : " + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4)
        );
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error checking/renewing token:", error);
  }
}
```

My example URL looks something like this:

```
KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME=myRealm
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=myClientID
KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:9080
KEYCLOAK_LOGOUT_URL=http://localhost:9080/realms/myRealm/protocol/openid-connect/logout
```

Previously Keycloak was using `/auth` and all which is not required anymore.